# How to identify a particular key in the responseJson?

Tags: jquery, json, servlets

I have a piece of code that calls servlet through ajax and returing response via **responseJSON**. Now I would like to identify particular key in the received responseJSON. I am passing below JSON ARRAY from servlet to jquery.

```
[{"parameters":"EXT","spec":"DAMAGE","actual1":"NO","actual2":"NO","actual3":"NO","actual4":"NO","actual5":"NO"}]
```

There may be a chance of not receiving actual1 key and its value in JSON array. now i would like to identify whether I am receiving actual1 key in received response.

I has tried with has OWN property. but no luck

```js
  

  $.ajax({
        url: 'PopulateTable2',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "inspinp": inspinp
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success: function(responseJson) {
            if (responseJson != null) {
              $("#tab_logic")
                .find("tr:gt(0)")
                .remove();
              var tableinsp = $("#tab_logic");
              $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
                var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");

              });
            }
```

Comment: if(responseJson && responseJson[0] && responseJson[0].actual1)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it works